# Lost Auth sessions in CakePHP Jquery Ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, session, cakephp, authentication

I made frequent Jquery Ajax calls (post, load) with my CakePHP app. Normally loading content into divs, and the content is related with the user who is logged in.

I use the default Form authentication, and define the logged in user in the AppController:

```
$this->aU = $this->User->findById($this->Auth->user('id'));
```

After this I normally use the logged in user in controllers with $this->aU and it works fine in normal view rendering.
But when I render views with ajax and setinterval, 1 time in 20 the call lost the session and the controller redirects the request, because cannot see the logged in user.

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  $('#alerts').load('<?php echo $this->Html->url('/users/alerts'); ?>');
}, 20000);
```

In UsersController alerts action I use this:

```
public function alerts() {
  $this->layout = 'ajax';
  $user = $this->aU;
  $this->loadModel('Message');
  $unread_messages = $this->Message->find('count', array(
    'conditions' => array('receiver_user_id' => $user['User']['id'])
  ));
  $this->set(compact('user', 'unread_messages'));
}
```

Maybe I use wrong logic in user identification?

Answer (score 0):

Test in your function for ajax call

```
public function alerts() {    
    if($this->request->is('ajax')){ //or $this->RequestHandler->isAjax() if you're in cake 1.3
       $this->layout = 'ajax';
       $user = $this->aU;
       $this->loadModel('Message');
       $unread_messages = $this->Message->find('count', array(
         'conditions' => array('receiver_user_id' => $user['User']['id'])
       ));
      $this->set(compact('user', 'unread_messages'));    
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hi Herod, is it more stable calling like this? I tried it before and I've seen it's the same.

Comment: try to debug $this->Auth->user('User.id') and $this->Auth->user('id') and see what is the value returning. one should be ok one should be null i guess

Comment: I tried again now and only $this->Auth->user('id') is fine. It seems this Auth user array is "sometimes" empty. 1 times in 20.

Comment: how does your beforeFilter callback looks like?

Comment: the AppController's beforeFilter is in my question
the UsersController's:
  parent::beforeFilter();
  $this->Auth->allow('add', 'login', 'logout', 'activate');

Comment: in your UserController in beforeFilter debug($this->aU) and see if you get any data

Comment: I try what you mentioned: if ($this->request->isAjax()) {}
and observe the result and will tell if it solves, thanks Herod!

Comment: unfortunately ajax losts auth user again - I have to do something more trickier :)